# What permissions to provide if not DB owner?

Tags: sql-server

From my readings, i found that db_owner permission should not be provided to application user. Instead, db_reader and db_writer should be provided. Now if we provide them with these two permissions they will still be unable to connect untill we map their objects. My question is, how can i map the user to these objects? Shall i ask them for a script? Or shall i let them do it by them selves(is that possible since i gave them db_writer)??  What commands will be used here? Any example? ThNks.

Comment: Iam talking about MSSQL login privliges in general. If i dont provide the application login with db_owner than how the user will insert/update/delete from the tables. Providibg db_writer it self without specifying tye tables wont be enough? Correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: Anyone can assist me with this? Thank you.